# Steps for creating a dll in C# that can then be used from php

Tags: c#, php, dll

By gleaning bits of information from various posts, I have come so far, but still not there yet.

I am trying to create a dll in C# which can then be used by php.

I have created a VS2012 C# class library project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test1
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("0283F337-AF8D-45BE-BD32-829F5976E9EF")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        public int blah()
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

Platform Target: Any CPU

Target framework: .NET Framework 4

I have compiled this and have got a test1.dll file.

I have tried registering it with:

```
regsvr32 test1.dll
```

but get the following error:

```
The module "test1.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
```

Also tried:

```
regsvr32 /i /n test1.dll
```

but I get this error:

```
The module "test1.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllInstall was not found.
```

I use:

```
regasm test1.dll
```

and that says it is successful.

I next create a test php file:

```
<?php
$obj = new COM("test1.Class1");
$output=$obj->blah();
echo $output;
?>
```

I also add the following to my php.ini:

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

but when I run it, I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
'Failed to create COM object `test1.Class1': Class not registered
```

So it seems to me that I have to use regsvr32 and make some changes in C# to deal with the DllRegisterServer issue

Can somebody fill me in on what else I need to do to make this work.

I am using:

```
PHP 5.6.7
Visual Studio Express 2012
Windows 8.1 (64 bit version)
```

**Addendum:**

Also tried:

```
regasm test1.dll /tlb:test1.tlb
regsvr32 test1.tlb
```

That gives me:

```
The module "test1.tlb" may not be compatible with the version of Windows
that you're running.  Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit)
or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.
```

I get that message whether the platform target is "x64" or "any CPU".

Comment: Copy your DLL in to system32 folder.
Goto system32 -> Run "cmd.exe" as `administrator` ( right click on the exe and select run as administrator)

then do this

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 "DLL name.dll"

Comment: Makes no difference - same message about the DllRegisterServer entry point

Comment: Did you ran `cmd` as `administrator`?

Comment: Are you running `64` bit versions of the Windows OS?

Comment: yes - ran as admin.  yes 64 bit windows 8.1.

Comment: Ok, then you need to use `%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe`

Comment: %systemroot% is C:\WINDOWS, so you had the right path

Comment: `test1.dll` is not really a COM dll, you can't register it. You need to convert your class library project to enable COM. Follow the link for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an answer, but is a bit of a work round.  It looks like the 64 bit version does not work in windows 8.1 or in VS2012 Express or the combination of both even though it is the 64 bit version of the OS.

If I build the solution with a platform target of x86, it all works fine.

I have also discovered that there are two regsvr32.exe files on windows 8.1, one in c:\windows\system32 and one in c:\windows\SysWoW64.  I've had no success with either of them.

The first is for registering 64 bit versions of Dlls and the second for 32 bit versions.

Fortunately for me, I don't need to have a 64 bit version.

That all said, I can only register it in VS, so I still have to figure out how to register it on the actual server.

**Addendum**

Got a step closer today - can now register it on my development PC at the cmd prompt

Steps involved:

- Run VS2012 express as administrator
- I removed the [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid... line as it seems that it is not needed
- I signed the assembly:

  - right click project name in solution explorer and select properties
  - Select "Signing"
  - Tick "Sign the assembly"
  - Choose "New..." under "Choose a strong name key file"
  - I gave mine a name of test1.snk and chose not to password protect it
- Build it (F7)
- At the cmd prompt (run as administrator):

  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe test1.dll /tlb:test1.tlb /codebase

This now works on my Windows 8.1 PC

I copy this over to the Win 2008 R2 server and try the same:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe test1.dll /tlb:test1.tlb /codebase
```

but I get a popup window with this error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe is not a valid Win32 application
```

followed by a "Access is denied." at the cmd prompt.

I have discovered that there are 12 different versions of regasm.exe installed on Win8.1 and 10 on Win2008R2.  I have tried them all, but the one that works is the one I have been using all along.

In case it's of use to anyone, here they are:

```
WIN 2008 R2
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.17514_none_a3c349b4bdac0898\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.18523_none_a3c462acbdab0575\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.22733_none_8cf7bc12d7517f23\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.17514_none_eb70808bd228319e\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.18523_none_eb719983d2272e7b\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.22733_none_d4a4f2e9ebcda829\RegAsm.exe

WIN 8.1
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.9600.16384_none_95117f30a7195a76\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.16384_none_ea742672c514173d\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.17226_none_ea6df930c519af4b\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.20708_none_d39e21d6dec31402\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.9600.16384_none_dcbeb607bb95837c\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.16384_none_32215d49d9904043\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.17226_none_321b3007d995d851\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_regasm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.3.9600.20708_none_1b4b58adf33f3d08\RegAsm.exe
```

So I'm a step closer, but still not quite there.  Still can't compile a 64 bit version (don't need it, but was hoping I could get that version to work on WIN2008R2) and can't register the 32 bit version (x86) on the server.

**Addendum2**

**Success** - finally.  I noticed that C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe had a size of zero bytes (goodness knows why), so I copied one from another win2008r2 server and all is well.  So I'm a happy man - don't care about the 64 bit version :-)

Answer (score 1):

`test1.dll` is not really a COM dll, you can't register it.

You need to follow the steps(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx) to enable COM.

[image]

**To set up the code in your class to create a COM object**

In Solution Explorer, double-click Class1.vb to display its code.
Rename the class to ComClass1.
Add the following constants to ComClass1. They will store the Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) constants that the COM objects are required to have.

VB.NET

```
Public Const ClassId As String = "" 
Public Const InterfaceId As String = "" 
Public Const EventsId As String = ""
```

On the Tools menu, click Create Guid. In the Create GUID dialog box, click Registry Format and then click Copy. Click Exit.

Replace the empty string for the ClassId with the GUID, removing the leading and trailing braces. For example, if the GUID provided by Guidgen is "{2C8B0AEE-02C9-486e-B809-C780A11530FE}" then your code should appear as follows.

VB.NET

```
Public Const ClassId As String = "2C8B0AEE-02C9-486e-B809-C780A11530FE"
```

Repeat the previous steps for the InterfaceId and EventsId constants, as in the following example.

VB.NET

```
Public Const InterfaceId As String = "3D8B5BA4-FB8C-5ff8-8468-11BF6BD5CF91" 
Public Const EventsId As String = "2B691787-6ED7-401e-90A4-B3B9C0360E31"
```

Make sure that the GUIDs are new and unique; otherwise, your COM component could conflict with other COM components.

Add the ComClass attribute to ComClass1, specifying the GUIDs for the Class ID, Interface ID, and Events ID as in the following example:

VB.NET

```
<ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)>
Public Class ComClass1
```

COM classes must have a parameterless `Public Sub New()` constructor, or the class will not register correctly. Add a parameterless constructor to the class:

VB.NET

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub
```

Add properties, methods, and events to the class, ending it with an End Class statement. Select Build Solution from the Build menu.

Now, you can register your dlls using `regsvr32`.

Comment: These steps are for VB, how do I do it in C#?

Comment: Thought I'd try the VB example in the link (even though I want C#) but when registering it, I get: "The module may not be compatible with the version of Windows that you're running."  So it looks like I might have some other issues, but don't know what though.  As the VB one is self registering (in VS) I thought I'd just give it a go in php, but I do not know how to reference it. `new COM("ComClass1")` and `new COM("ClassLibrary1.ComClass1")` both give me a syntax error.